# python logging into file as well as wxpython txt ctrl

Tags: python, logging, wxpython

How can I log into a file as well as to to wxpython txt ctrl ?

Background I have wxpython GUI based application which enumerates python test files and executes them. With the help of http://broadcoder.blogspot.com/2009/10/redirecting-python-logging-to.html I was able to redirect python logging messages to the txtctrl. However I will also like to redirect logging messages to log files also.
 I import my testfiles like this:

```
     logging.info('Started')
     testid = __import__(str)
     reload(testid)

     testOut = testid.main()
```

In each of my testfiles I simply use import logging and my logging messages get redirected to the txt ctrl. However I would also like that the test log messages also be redirected to a log file based on the name of the file. How do I redirect my log messages to both?
If I use logging.basicConfig in my test file messages are still directed only to the text ctrl. My TestGUI.py in which I  import say 5 python test files. In my test file files I simply use import logging while I setup the logger in my TestGUI.py file

```
    self.logr = logging.getLogger('')
    self.logr.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    hdlr = WxLog(self.log)
    hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s '))
    self.logr.addHandler(hdlr)
```

In my test file I do something like this:

```
      logger = logging.getLogger('')   
      fh = logging.FileHandler("log.html",mode='w')
      formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
      fh.setFormatter(formatter)
      logger.addHandler(fh)
      a= 5
      b= 6

      logging.info('a=5')
      logging.info('b=6')
      c= a+b
      logging.info('adding b and  c')
      fh.close()
```

I get ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when I run this test more than once .

Comment: One Logger can have multiple handlers ! so you can achieve this easily.

Comment: Duh forgot about this I got it

Comment: @shahjapan: Could you please post you answer as an answer, and then the OP can accept it, and then the rest of us will know that this question has been answered and we won't all read it.  Yes, it's a short answer, but it is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One Logger can have multiple handlers ! so you can achieve this easily.

example

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('var/myapp.log')
hdlr2 = logging.FileHandler('var/myapp2.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
hdlr2.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.addHandler(hdlr2)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('a log message')
```